# Which US Secretaries of State have been sacked?

Tags: united-states

It appears that President Trump has dismissed his Secretary of State, Rex Tillerson. It further appears that this is a very clear "sacking".

*Which other Secretaries of State in the USA have been fired by the President, or forced to resign with no attempt to make the resignation appear to be by mutual consent?*

I'm aware of the [resignation of Alexander Haig](https://www.nytimes.com/1982/06/26/world/haig-resigns-over-foreign-policy-course-but-cites-no-issues-reagan-names-shultz.html), but it isn't clear if he left at the instruction of President Reagan, or of his own choosing.

Comment: It's worse than sacking. Tillerson apparently learned about it through the news, and the latter learned about it on Twitter.

Comment: Generally, when a Cabinet member resigns in during the term, and there is controversy around them, it's best to read that the resignation was forced (POTUS said leave with dignity or leave without it.).  I can't find any source that they were directly fired, but dismissal is rare (at least for this post).

Comment: This is definitely the first time that a Secretary of State has been fired on Twitter in a tweet he was not even copied on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hard to define "sacked" in this context, since if you want to fire someone you could just as easily "ask" them to resign. There are also a couple of instances of people being offered a "promotion" to an ambassadorship, which also would conveniently remove them from the local political scene. Below is an entire (to date) list of U.S. Secretaries of State and my interpreted reasons for why they left their posts. This information was mostly gleaned from their associated Wikipedia pages.

By my count there are 4 instances of outright "sacking" highlighted in bold below(Timothy Pickering, Edward Livingston, James G. Blaine, and Rex Tillerson). Some others, such as Edmund Randolph and Robert Lansing, are not quite as clear cut.

1. Thomas Jefferson - *Resigned* to focus on rallying support against the influence of Alexander Hamilton and John Jay.
2. Edmund Randolph - *Resigned* following a scandal after the British intercepted a French message containing information Randolph shared but shouldn't have.
3. **Timothy Pickering** - *Dismissed* by John Adams after quarreling over John Adams' attempt to make peace with France during the [Quasi-War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-War).
4. John Marshall - Served through the end of Adams' term, later appointed to Supreme Court.
5. James Madison - Served throughout Jefferson's terms, later elected President.
6. Robert Smith - *Resigned*, though after refusing the "promotion" of Ambassador to Russia and publicly criticizing President Madison.
7. James Monroe - *Resigned* two months after the British burned the U.S. Capitol and the White House. He was serving a dual role at the time as also the U.S. Secretary of War, and after his resignation there was no immediate successor appointed so he was the *de facto* Secretary of State for another six months. Later elected President.
8. John Quincy Adams - Served throughout Monroe's two terms, later elected President.
9. Henry Clay - Served throughout J.Q. Adams' term.
10. Martin Van Buren - *Resigned* following a split in Andrew Jackson's cabinet, the [*Petticoat Affair*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petticoat_affair)
11. **Edward Livingston** - *Replaced* with Louis McLane by President Jackson in a Cabinet shakeup and attempt to undermine the creation of the Second Bank of the United States.
12. Louis McLane - *Resigned* after being undermined by Martin Van Buren in negotiating with the French.
13. John Forsyth - Served the remainder of Jackson's administration and the entirety of Martin Van Buren's term. Died 7 months after leaving office.
14. Daniel Webster - *Resigned* All Whigs under President John Tyler resigned their cabinet positions while he was in Europe, and he ultimately acceeded to their pressure to also resign.
15. Abel Upshur - Died in Office aboard the USS Princeton when a ceremonial firing of her guns caused the gun to burst, spraying shrapnel into the crowd.
16. John C. Calhoun - Served the remainder of President Tyler's term. Later he was elected Senator from South Carolina. Earlier he was Vice President under both John Q. Adams and Andrew Jackson.
17. James Buchanan - Served throughout President Polk's term. Later elected President.
18. John M. Clayton - *Resigned* after President Taylor's death.
19. Daniel Webster - Died in Office after being appointed by President Fillmore. He fell from a horse and suffered a crush to the head, complicated by cirrhosis of the liver. This is the same person as #14.
20. Edward Everett - *Resigned* under pressure from abolitionists and failing health during the debate over the Kansas-Nebraska act.
21. William L. Marcy - Served throughout President Pierce's term.
22. Lewis Cass - *Resigned* over disagreements with President Buchanan's disposition of federal forces in the south.
23. Jeremiah S. Black - Served through the remainder of President Buchanan's term.
24. William H. Seward - Served throughout President Lincoln's terms.
25. Elihu B. Washburne - *Resigned* after 11 days due to illness.
26. Hamilton Fish - Served throughout President Grant's terms.
27. William M. Evarts - Served throughout President Hayes' term.
28. **James G. Blaine** - *Resigned*  under extreme pressure after President Garfield was assassinated and President Arthur's stalwarts assumed power.
29. Frederick T. Frelinghuysen - Served the remainder of Garfield's term.
30. Thomas F. Bayard - Served throughout President Cleveland's term.
31. James G. Blaine - *Resigned* due to failing health. This is the same person as #28.
32. John W. Foster - Served through the remainder of President Harrison's term.
33. Walter Q. Gresham - Died in Office.
34. Richard Olney - Served through the remainder of President Cleveland's term.
35. John Sherman - *Resigned* due to declining health. He was 73 when first appointed, and the President took council more from Assistant Secretary of State William Day than him.
36. William R. Day - *Resigned* after 5 months to work on the U.S. Peace Commission formed to negotiate an end to the Spanish-American War. Later served as Associate Justice on the Supreme Court.
37. John M. Hay - Died in Office from heart ailment and complications.
38. Elihu Root - *Resigned* after being elected Senator from New York.
39. Robert Bacon - Served the final 38 days of President Theodore Roosevelt's term after Root's resignation.
40. Philander C. Knox - Served throughout President Taft's term.
41. William J. Bryan - *Resigned* in protest to President Wilson's belligerant tone towards Germany after the sinking of the Lusitania.
42. Robert Lansing - *Resigned* after President Wilson suffered a stroke and susequent illness. Lansing proposed Vice President Marshall assume the Presidency, and Wilson's wife Edith asked for his resignation.
43. Bainbridge Colby - Served the remainder of President Wilson's term.
44. Charles E. Hughes - *Resigned*. President Harding died and was succeeded by President Coolidge, Hughes resigned after Coolidge was re-elected. Was later Chief Justice of the Supreme Court.
45. Frank B. Kellogg - Served throughout President Coolidge's term.
46. Henry L. Stimson - Served throughout President Hoover's term.
47. Cordell Hull - *Resigned* due to failing health after 11 years under President Roosevelt and during World War II.
48. Edward R. Stettinius, Jr. - *Resigned* to take up position as first U.S. Ambassador to the United Nations.
49. James F. Byrnes - *Resigned* after being named *TIME* Man of the Year caused interpersonal issues between him and President Truman.
50. George C. Marshall - *Resigned* due to ill health.
51. Dean G. Acheson - Served the remainder of President Truman's term.
52. John F. Dulles - *Resigned* due to ill health.
53. Christian A. Herter - Served the remainder of President Eisenhower's term.
54. David Dean Rusk - Served throughout President Kennedy and President Johnson's terms.
55. William P. Rogers - *Resigned*. Some believe it is because he was continuously sidelined in favor of National Security Advisor Henry Kissinger.
56. Henry A. Kissinger - Served the remainder of President Nixon's and President Ford's terms.
57. Cyrus R. Vance - *Resigned* in protest to President Carter agreement to attempt to rescue hostages in Iran without informing him.
58. Edmund S. Muskie - Served the remainder of President Carter's term.
59. Alexander Haig - *Resigned* after causing a few scandals of his own (such as suggesting a nuclear warning shot in Europe to counter Soviet aggression).
60. George P. Shultz - Served the remainder of President Reagan's term.
61. James A. Baker - *Resigned* to become President George H.W. Bush's Chief of Staff.
62. Lawrence S. Eagleburger - Served the remainder of President George H.W. Bush's term.
63. Warren M. Christopher - *Resigned* after President Clinton's first term.
64. Madeleine K. Albright - Served the remainder of President Clinton's term.
65. Colin L. Powell - *Resigned* after being asked to by Chief of Staff Andrew Card.
66. Condoleezza Rice - Served the remainder of President Bush's term.
67. Hillary R. Clinton - *Resigned* after indicating she did not wish to serve a second term under President Obama.
68. John Kerry - Served the remainder of President Obama's term.
69. **Rex Tillerson** - *Replaced* by CIA Director Mike Pompeo (subject to official announcement and Senate confirmation) after a rocky relationship with President Trump.

Comment: #69. *"... after a rocky relationship with President Trump."* This is media speculation. I'm not saying it's not potentially true, but you're advancing an unsourced media narrative. There's nobody in the administration that has characterized the relationship between Trump and Tillerson as anything other than cordial and respectful. Maybe it was just two strong-willed people who couldn't agree on something.

Comment: @Michael_B And you in turn are advancing a narrative that benefits the current administration. It is completely true I'm taking some liberties with this list all over, but it is my _best guess_ attempt to come up with [the reasoning](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/white-house/amp/tillerson-s-fury-trump-required-intervention-pence-n806451) behind his leaving.

Comment: By implying that you should source an assertion, I'm not taking a side at all. Just trying to keep a wall up between facts and opinion.

Comment: If you would like a source just ask for one, I'll happily provide it. But believing anyone in the administration (especially one that has been so loose with the truth) is no different than believing anything the "media" puts out.

Comment: We're getting a bit off-topic here, but it's not up to the media to decide the truth. Their job is to report the news. Then you, me and others get to decide on the veracity. Once the media decides what the "truth" is, things are really lost by the time they reach us. That's why the administration's official line matters.

Comment: Regardless, you put together a great list.

Comment: @Michael_B That I can agree with (that the administration's official line matters). I just find it much easier in this specific case to discount the official line, personally. I apologize for initial defensiveness.

Comment: @Michael_B: While I can vaguely agree with the notion that it's not the media's job to report the truth, I for one would argue that it's their job to report something as close to the truth as they can. They _can_ and do spin this in various ways. But your comment makes it sound like there is no such a thing as something that is factually correct, which is weird or worse. One can argue with opinions; but not with facts.

Comment: It boils down to this for me: If the administration hasn't provided the slightest hint of a "rocky relationship", or anything other than mutual respect between the two men, but the news media is reporting such turmoil between them for months, what is the media's source or basis for that characterization? How do they know? I haven't seen anything in that regard. It could be pure speculation or worse, outright dishonesty. So when Jeff went with that characterization, in an otherwise fact-based answer, I chimed in. @DenisdeBernardy

Comment: Dammit I was just five words away from reading all 69 items and completing the answer without comment.

Comment: @Michael_B I went ahead and made it a community wiki, so anyone should feel free to update any characterization I may have either misunderstood or misquoted. I figure it's a good idea anyway because it's a pretty big list.

Comment: @Michael_B When a secretary of state pointedly avoids answering whether he called his boss a moron when asked by reporters, I feel safe to say that they have what can be termed a "rocky relationship".

Comment: Well, you shouldn't feel so safe to say that because you could easily be wrong. There are other possibilities. For example, maybe Tillerson felt that the question was so idiotic that he refused to dignify it with a response. No? If I make an outrageous claim about you, your best response may be to ignore me. By actually responding you would be legitimizing my question, going beneath your dignity, and opening yourself up to that line of questioning. @Teleka

Comment: @Michael_B Facts don't exist in a vacuum, they build on each other to form a coherent narrative.  For example, if Trump and Tillerson had a great relationship, and the question was so ridiculous to not warrant an answer, would Trump respond to the moron comment along the lines of "if he did that, I guess we’ll have to compare IQ tests. And I can tell you who is going to win"?

Comment: Honestly, assuming Trump did say that, it sounds like something you say when you're messing with a friend. Read it again. That comment could just as easily suggest they are good friends. @Teleka

Comment: Back to the original point. Here's some proof that he may simply not want to answer a stupid question: https://binged.it/2Ip3zer

Comment: Sebastian Gorka, a former senior WH aide, just stated in a TV news interview that he was informed by a cabinet member back in December that the plan was to replace Tillerson with Pompeo. So, assuming he's telling the truth, this is part of a longer-term strategy. It comes as a surprise to the mainstream news media because, for the most part, they have no access to this WH. They're kept out of the loop. But they characterize the timing of administration actions based on when they learn about them, not when the process actually began.

Comment: @Michael_B A man thin-skinned enough to tell the world that he's a "stable genius" doesn't seem like the kind of guy to offer good-natured jokes in response to allegations of someone calling him a moron, but  you do you.  If a guy being fired via Twitter isn't enough for you, a good faith discussion was pointless from the start.